# How can I move one table from one database to other database

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, linux

I want to move one table in one database to other database using mysql dump on linux terminal How can I go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Take dump of a particular table from the particular database.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases DBname --tables Tablename > xxyy.sql
```

Import the table into new database.

```
mysql -u root -p newDBname < xxyy.sql
```

If you want to rename the table.

```
rename table dbname.tablename to dbname.newtablename;
```